# Horizontal vs vertical data approach in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, query-optimization

I am creating analytics module in our 'Tours & Travels' application.

Following are the steps through which user has to go in our application:

*Step 1:* User search tours for any city.

*Step 2:* User views the details of the tour.

*Step 3:* If user finds perfect tour for him/her, he/she book the tour.

*Step 4:* While booking the tour user enter passenger details.

*Step 5:* User reviews the final data.

*Step 6:* User pays online & tour gets booked.

Now I want to store the users each activity on our system for our analysis purpose. For this I have below table structure:

| Id | user_id | tour_id | city_id | searched_at | viewed_at | entered_pax_info_at | reviewed_at | booked_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 151 | 34 | 678 | 1290 | 2021-03-14 12:00:00 | 2021-03-14 12:05:00 | 2021-03-14 12:10:00 | 2021-03-14 12:15:00 | 2021-03-14 12:20:00 |

**Now while analyzing the data from this structure, *Admin user* may want data based on below columns:**

- searched_at

or

- viewed_at

or

- entered_pax_info_at

or

- reviewed_at

or

- booked_at

Eg. Admin user can ask the data like - Give me report of tour 'ABC' which got booked from Jan 2021 to March 2021. etc...

Now to make such **searches on huge data efficiently**, I will have to put **indexes** on each above mentioned column. By doinng this there will be **no efficiency problem while reading** the data, but **it will cost** me while **writing, updating** operations.

To counter above problem I am thinking below structure table:

| id | user_id | tour_id | city_id | activity_type | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | 34 | 678 | 1290 | searched | 2021-03-14 12:00:00 |
| 51 | 34 | 678 | 1290 | viewed | 2021-03-14 12:05:00 |
| 52 | 34 | 678 | 1290 | pax_info | 2021-03-14 12:10:00 |
| 53 | 34 | 678 | 1290 | reviewed | 2021-03-14 12:15:00 |
| 54 | 34 | 678 | 1290 | booked | 2021-03-14 12:20:00 |

Now to make **searches on huge data efficiently** on above table structure, I may have to put **indexes** only on *activity_type* & *date* column.

**But accoding to me disadvantage of this stucture is that it is going to take large space comparively to the first approach.**

I am left with confusion which approch (among above two or any other) will be future proof in terms of scalability, efficacy.

Any help to sort out this would be appreciated.

Comment: Writing and updating on a data set of this type is going to be incredibly low overhead. At the point at which that's no longer true, either you will be rich enough to engage professional help, or too rich to care. *(Love of) premature optimisation is the root of all evil*

Comment: How many rows in this table?  How many inserts/updates per _second_?  A million rows is probably not a problem.  100 modifications per second is probably not a problem.

Comment: Am I correct in saying that there will be only 0 or 1 "booking", but all the other items can happen repeatedly?  This says that those dates _cannot_ be columns in a single table.

Comment: While I agree with "... premature optimization ...", we can at least push you in some general directions to get you off to a better footing.  (A common example, in other situations, is warning of the evils of EAV.)

Comment: Or maybe the column could be "FIRST_viewed_at"?  That can easily be handled with a slightly more complex IODKU.

Answer (score 2):

Your second alternative is far better than your first. It allows your system to be flexible about the number of steps you will analyze, for one thing. Normalized (vertical) tables almost always scale up better than denormalized (horizontal) tables.

And about the space used by your tables and indexes? [Fuggedaboudit](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fuggedaboudit)! Disk / SSD space is really cheap, and getting expomemtially cheaper by the month.

Unless your system already has tens of millions of rows AND your database administrator is pressuring you to denormalize your tables for performance's sake, do not worry about the size of your tables. Seriously.

Answer (score 1):

The analytic database should not not the operational database.  In fact, I often work with analytic databases that are batch updated and rarely -- if ever -- have updates.  Typically, analysts don't like their data changing under them as they are solving a problem.

In other words, either you need to rethink your approach or you have not described the full problem.

The first table you described looks like a good *summary* table for users that might be quite appropriate for analysts.  It is not appropriate as an operational store for the data.  In the world I live in, people are not so consistent about their searches.  They search for the best tour in one city, find the price and other details, go back and check others.  And so on.  This is "navigation" and "path analysis", which your structure does not allow.

Such a summary table can be produced in a batch process.  Even on a relatively large amount of data, that might take just a minute or two and it might be sufficient to do it once per day.  If so, problem solved.  There are no updates.  The indexes are the ones needed on the analytic side.

On the other hand, there is lots of analysis that is this structure does not support.  For instance, how many cities did a user look at before deciding on the final city?  Well, maybe you could eke out the answer to that question.

Comment: Further, the interesting indexes are on the Summary tables, not the "Fact table".  The latter needs little more than a unique key.  Summary tables are one-tenth the size of a Fact table.

Comment: "How many cities" requires knowing that two clicks came from the same person.  This requires a login _before_ browsing.  That is a business decision.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need 2 tables

- one for browsing activity.  In this situation, you probably should not even identify the user; let them be anonymous.
- one for booking, paying, etc.  (Probably more than one table, due to normalization, etc.)

The browsing table probably only gets `INSERTs`, and lots of them.  If there will be many millions of rows, then we should talk about "summary tables".  You don't have to decide on what, exactly, they summarize, but instead wait until the admins have requested some "reports".

The booking table(s) will have fewer `INSERTs` and possibly more `UPDATEs` than `INSERTs`.